# Order by the greater column

Tags: sql-server

I have two column for stored time named :
Time_1 | Time_2

I want to make a SQL query that select all table, then order the result by compare between Time_1 vs Time_2 to get the greater (newer) value of each row and order all result by that greater value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
order by case when Time_1 >= Time_2 then Time_1 
              else Time_2
         end desc
```